# How to create new Parse.Object with relation in Parse-SDK-JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

[Docs](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#many-to-many) say it is required to create relation type column in the dashboard prior to adding any relations to object:

> In the Data Browser, you can create a column on the Book object of
>   type relation and name it authors.

Is it possible to create it from js sdk level? I tried something like here:

```
book.save(null).then(saved => {
  let relation = new Parse.Relation(saved.id, "authors");
  relation.add(author);
  saved.save(null);
}
```

But it can not be saved saying `TypeError: this.parent.set is not a function`

I know I can add it manually in the dashboard as stated, but the idea is to create new classes automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a relation with the [Javascript Parse SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS) you need to work directly with your object:

For example:

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
var relation = user.relation("mylikes");
relation.add(post); // Post is a Parse Object
user.save();
```

In your case, I think you want something like that:

```
book.save(null).then(saved => {
    var relation = saved.relation("authors");
    relation.add(author);
    saved.save(null);
}
```

I hope my answer was helpful

Comment: I was sure I tried it at the beginning. It seems sometimes data browser doesn't show latest updates. Thanks!

Comment: @BartBiczBoży You're welcome, If you want to refresh your object you can use the fetch method

Answer (score 0):

***I will Show you how to add a pointer and relation in Parse***

```
Parse.User.currentAsync().then((current) => {
  if (current) {
    var pharmacy = new Parse.Object("Pharmacy");
   // add a pointer here
    pharmacy.set("owner", current);
    pharmacy
      .save()
      .then((pharmacy) => {
        //   add a relation here
        var relation = current.relation("pharmacy");
        relation.add(pharmacy)
        current.save()};

  }
});
```